# ABUnknownPersonViewController remove "Text Message" button

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

Does anyone have any idea how to remove the "Text Message" button for this controller? It automatically shows up when a number is set.

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: can you post how you removed the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the allowActions to NO on your ABUnknownPersonViewController

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix my situation.  I had to traverse the view hierarchy and hide the button manually.  I wanted the ability to "Add/Create" a new contact, jut not text message.  It seems strange that there is not a bitmask or something that you can customize what actions are available.

Comment: @Freddie, can you post how you removed the button?